# what does this refer to in this scenario

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Normally im using *this* keyword in Jquery to refer to an element, but in my current code it is not behaving as expected.

This is my code (the relevant part)

```
  $("#myTable tbody").on('sortstart', 'tr', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).children("td").css({'background-color': '#313131'});
  });
```

I would expect *this* to mean tr in this case, but it doesnt. What does it refer to?

the whole thing, if anyone wants to have a look:

http://jsbin.com/ucopun/102/edit

Comment: Good way to figure out these things is `console.log();`. You could put `console.log( $(this) );` inside your event and then check the console to see what `$(this)` points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does refer to the `tr`, but the problem is that the event `sortstart` never triggers. Try changing the event to for example `click` and it works just fine.

The `sortstart` event doesn't get triggered because you're binding the handler to the `tr` children, not to the `tbody` that has been initialized as sortable. A sortable object's children don't trigger the event.